# Help understanding a statement in Hoffman and Kunze

Tags: linear-algebra

So in the book on linear algebra it was stated that if a system of linear combinations is created from another system of equations, then every solution from the system of base equations is a solution of the linear combinations but not necessarily the other way around. I cant think of why this would be the case. How are extra solutions created in the system of linear combinations? Can you maybe give an example?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $(x,y,z)$ satisfies $x+2y+3z=0$, then $(x,y,z)$ satisfies $0(x+2y+3z)=0$, but just because $(x,y,z)$ satisfies $0(x+2y+3z)=0$ doesn't mean $(x,y,z)$ satisfies $x+2y+3z=0$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Ok, that makes sense thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.

If $(x,y,z)$ satisfies $x+2y+3z=0$, then $(x,y,z)$ satisfies $0(x+2y+3z)=0$,

but if $(x,y,z)$ satisfies $0(x+2y+3z)=0$

that doesn't necessarily mean that $(x,y,z)$ satisfies $x+2y+3z=0$.

Manipulating equations often introduces extraneous solutions.

For a non-linear example of that, note that squaring both sides shows that $x=2$ means $x^2=4$,

but $x^2=4$ doesn't necessarily mean that $x=2$.  (It could be that $x=-2$.)